# Levee, circuit breaker pattern, throwing an exception when it is executed

Tags: node.js, microservices

I am new to the Node.js and I came across levee which is used as circuit breaker, when I execute the following code, The exception occurs

```
   'use   strict';

    var  Levee = require('levee');
    var  Wreck = require('wreck');

    var options, circuit;

    options = {
        maxFailures: 5,
        timeout: 60000,
        resetTimeout: 30000
    };

    circuit = Levee.createBreaker(Wreck.get,       options);

    circuit.run('https://www.google.com',        function (err, req, payload)
     {
        // If the service fails or timeouts occur 5 consecutive times,
        // the breaker opens, fast failing subsequent requests.
        console.log(err || payload);
    });
```

And the Exception is as follows

```
TypeError: this._shortcut is not a function
    at Object.internals.Client.get [as execute] (/Users/amolmohandeshpande/Documents/node/node_modules/wreck/lib/index.js:580:17) 
    at zalgo (/Users/amolmohandeshpande/Documents/node/node_modules/levee/lib/zalgo.js:28:12) 
    at Breaker._run (/Users/amolmohandeshpande/Documents/node/node_modules/levee/lib/breaker.js:126:13) 
    at Breaker.run (/Users/amolmohandeshpande/Documents/node/node_modules/levee/lib/breaker.js:60:15) 
    at Object. (/Users/amolmohandeshpande/Documents/node/server.js:15:9) 
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30) 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10) 
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32) 
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12) 
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

Comment: According to the exception stacktrace, there is an error on your file `/Users/amolmohandeshpande/Documents/node/server.js` line 15. Which seems not to be the piece of code you copy/paste here. This piece of code is exactly the same as in levee's [documentation](https://github.com/krakenjs/levee#basic-usage) and I bet it is working out of the box :)

Comment: That is the name of the file in which I have pasted the code, so according to the line 15 this is the code    circuit.run('https://www.google.com',        function (err, req, payload) where I am getting error

Comment: Feels weird to have an error in the example from the documentation what's why I though the error was somewhere else. But if that's the case you might want to one an issue on github for that.